# Python / json : Check content of keys that may or may not exist

Tags: python, json, key, exists

For those familiar with imageboards, an OP post may or may not contain a 'subject' and a 'comment'

I wrote this to search all pages of a given board for thread subjects and OP posts.

If my search term exists on one of them but the other key is inexistent it will not get appended to my res list.

So how do I search json keys where 1 key or the other may not exist?

```py
import urllib, json, HTMLParser

def s4Chan(board, search):
  logo = '3::54chan'
  res = []
  p = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

  catalog = json.load(urllib.urlopen('https://api.4chan.org/%s/catalog.json' % board))

  for i in catalog:
    for j in i['threads']:
      try:
        if search.lower() in j['sub'].lower() or search.lower() in j['com'].lower():
          subject = j['sub']
          post = p.unescape(str(j['com'])).replace('<br>', ' ')

          if len(post) > 300:
            post = post[0:300]
            post = post + '...'

          text = str('%s /%s/ %s | %s | %s (R:%s, I:%s)' % (logo, board, subject, post, 'https://4chan.org/%s/res/%s' % (board, j['no']), j['replies'], j['images']))
          res.append(text)

      except(KeyError):
        continue
  return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.load` returns objects as Python dictionaries. You can, for example, use the [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of `dict`:

```
if search.lower() in j.get('sub', '').lower() or search.lower() in j.get('com', '').lower():
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I had to change a few lines in the loop and I got to remove the Exception.